# Elasticsearch field limitation

Tags: database, elasticsearch, indexing, nosql

I would like to have elasticsearch fields in a range of TCP/UDP network ports, 0~65535. I have already been informed that its limit is 1000. I also heard that I could fix this limit. However, Can it have such a wide range of fields?

Comment: So you would like to have documents containing up to 65535 fields? I'm curious about your use case.

Comment: Yes, i will record a connection attempt count for each port

Comment: It'd be much better and performant to have one document per port, so you get 65535 documents for each port check. `{"port": 12563, "attempt": succeeded"}`. That way it'll be much easier to work on the data afterwards. What kind of queries will you need to make?

Comment: According to your advice, each document will be made in a list of documents including port numbers and their counts, `[{"port": 12563, "count": 50}, {"port": 80, "count": 65} .....]` . I expect some count numbers are possibly updated frequently.
In this case, what would be a efficient way of search and update those documents and fields in them?

Comment: I'm not suggesting a document with an array of ports, but separate documents for each port. The id of the document could be the port number... Depends on your use case and what kind of queries you want to make.

Comment: If you would like this comment to post below as  an answer, I will pick yours for my answer. Thank you for a great deal of advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd be much better and performant to have one separate document per port, so you get 65535 documents for each port check. The id of the document could be the port number:

```
{"port": 12563, "attempt": "succeeded"}
{"port": 12564, "attempt": "failed"}
...
```

That way it'll be much easier to work on the data afterwards.